# Can awk be told to count the character string length rather than byte string length for '%10s' printf formats?

Tags: awk, unicode, character-encoding

Try this for an output of `|Ü| X|`:

```bash
echo 'Ü X' | awk '{printf("|% 2s|% 2s|\n", $1, $2)}'
```

Obviously `awk` counts the byte length, not the character length of the `Ü`, so the count is 2 and no left padding with space is needed, as is for the `X`.

Is it possible to run `awk` in a mode which counts **character** lengths for the `%<count>s` `printf` pattern, not byte length?

The [same question exists for `bash`'s `printf`](https://superuser.com/a/1599024/345087). I hope the answer is not the same: "passthrough to libc printf" :-/

I was **not** using `gawk`, but whatever version [Ubuntu 22.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_22.04_LTS_(Jammy_Jellyfish)) (Jammy Jellyfish) had installed for me. It did not occur to me that anything but `gawk` could be installed these days :-/

Comment: Are you using a Unicode locale? Which awk? With GNU awk 5.2.2 on Arch Linux in `en_GB.UTF-8`, I get `| Ü| X|`, with a space for padding for both. And if I use `LANG=C awk ...`, then `|Ü| X|`.

Comment: See also [Why is printf "shrinking" umlaut?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/350240)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**GNU awk** (and possibly some other awk variants):

```
$ echo 'Ü X' | LC_ALL='en_US.UTF-8' awk '{printf "|% 2s|% 2s|\n", $1, $2}'
| Ü| X|
```

**Bash 3.0+** (and possibly some other shells, possibly with tweaks):

```
$ LC_ALL='en_US.UTF-8' a='Ü' b='X'
$ printf '|%*s%s|%*s%s|\n' "$(( 2 - ${#a} ))" '' "$a" "$(( 2 - ${#b} ))" '' "$b"
| Ü| X|
```

Note that the bash version has to set `LC_ALL` in the shell that is executing `${#a}`, not just in `printf`s environment as is happening with the `awk` version, and so if you don't want `LC_ALL` to change in the calling shell you need to save/restore it, i.e. `o="$LC_ALL"; LC_ALL='en_US.UTF-8' ... "$b"; LC_ALL="$o"`, or do everything in a subshell, i.e. `( LC_ALL='en_US.UTF-8' ... "$b" )`.

**Explanations:**

From the [GNU awk documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Options):

> ```
> -b
> --characters-as-bytes
> ```
>
> Cause gawk to treat all input data as single-byte characters. In addition, all output written with print or printf is treated as
> single-byte characters.
>
> Normally, gawk follows the POSIX standard and attempts to process its
> input data according to the current locale (see [Where You Are Makes a
> Difference](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Locales)). This can often involve converting multibyte characters
> into wide characters (internally), and can lead to problems or
> confusion if the input data does not contain valid multibyte
> characters. This option is an easy way to tell gawk, “Hands off my
> data!”

Using GNU awk 5.2.2 setting an appropriate locale will treat multi-byte characters as single multi-byte characters:

```
$ echo 'Ü X' | LC_ALL='en_US.UTF-8' awk '{printf "|% 2s|% 2s|\n", $1, $2}'
| Ü| X|
```

whereas using a different locale, or using `-b`, will treat all input as single-byte characters:

```
$ echo 'Ü X' | LC_ALL='C' awk '{printf "|% 2s|% 2s|\n", $1, $2}'
|Ü| X|

$ echo 'Ü X' | awk -b '{printf "|% 2s|% 2s|\n", $1, $2}'
|Ü| X|
```

When `-b` is used the result is independent of your locale:

```
$ echo 'Ü X' | LC_ALL='en_US.UTF-8' awk -b '{printf "|% 2s|% 2s|\n", $1, $2}'
|Ü| X|

$ echo 'Ü X' | LC_ALL='C' awk -b '{printf "|% 2s|% 2s|\n", $1, $2}'
|Ü| X|
```

As [@StéphaneChazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%c3%a9phane-chazelas) mentioned in [a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/761031/can-awk-be-told-to-count-the-character-string-length-rather-than-byte-string-len#comment1451168_761031), see [Why is printf "shrinking" umlaut?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/350240/why-is-printf-shrinking-umlaut) for the related behavior of `printf` in shell where [@Léa Gris's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/592479/133219) suggests this will get the character counts, and so the formatted output, correct in bash 3.0 and later:

```
$ a='Ü' b='X' LC_ALL='en_US.UTF-8' 
$ printf '|%*s%s|%*s%s|\n' "$(( 2 - ${#a} ))" '' "$a" "$(( 2 - ${#b} ))" '' "$b"
| Ü| X|
```

and that functionality is also affected by locale:

```
$ LC_ALL='C'
$ printf "|%*s%s|%*s%s|\n" "$(( 2 - ${#a} ))" '' "$a" "$(( 2 - ${#b} ))" '' "$b"
|Ü| X|
```

See also [length-of-string-in-bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17368067/length-of-string-in-bash) for more information on getting the length of characters in bash.

Comment: Beware `gawk -b` triggers a warning when there's a `POSIXLY_CORRECT` variable in the environment.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas and also when `--posix` is used, which makes sense as they're contradictory.

Comment: But despite the `awk: warning: '--posix' overrides '--characters-as-bytes'` warning, I find that `echo é | POSIXLY_CORRECT= awk -b '{printf "|%2s|\n", $0}'` outputs `|é|` not `| é|` which would contradict that statement (here with 5.0.1)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas the output would then depend on your locale as that's the POSIX behavior. Try `echo é | LC_ALL='en_US.UTF-8' POSIXLY_CORRECT= awk -b '{printf "|%2s|\n", $0}'`

Comment: Yes, that's what I tried. Without -b, I get `| é|`, with I get `|é|` regardless of whether POSIXLY_CORRECT is in the environment or not. Maybe that was fixed in newer versions.

Comment: Could be. For me on gawk 5.2.2 `echo é | LC_ALL='C' POSIXLY_CORRECT= awk -b '{printf "|%2s|\n", $0}'` outputs `|é|` while `echo é | LC_ALL='en_US.UTF-8' POSIXLY_CORRECT= awk -b '{printf "|%2s|\n", $0}'` outputs `| é|` with the ```awk: warning: `--posix' overrides `--characters-as-bytes'``` warning in both cases.